# How can we avoid duplication/repeatition of methods in controllers - RAILS 3+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I am building a sample e-commerce app using ruby on rails.One of my controller name is "products_controller".This controller is also placed inside as a nested controller.The actions inside these controllers are same.How can we represent these actions without duplication of codes.
The code samples are given below.

app/controllers/products_controller.rb

```
def index
@product = Product.all
@vari = @products.variants
.............
.............
end
```

app/controllers/master_admins/products_controller.rb

```
def index
@product = Product.all
@vari = @products.variants
.............
.............
end
```

app/controllers/master_admins/properties_controller.rb

```
def product
@product = Product.all
@vari = @products.variants
.............
.............
end
```

The above actions contains the same set of codes.How can we refactor this so that the code doesnt get repeated.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I think a better question is why do you need multiple controllers with the same code? If you're worried about access control, why not handle that using roles?

Comment: am using this set of codes in nested controllers also.This product controller index action happens in the following urls in my project. "localhost:3000/products","localhost:3000/master_admins/products", "localhost:3000/property_admins/products".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) which are awesome for DRY.

For the controller, common methods can be placed here:

**In my app/controllers/concerns/common.rb**

```
module Common
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    ## This is a Class method, call it just like you call any other class method
    def get_products_and_variants
      @product = Self.all
      @vari = @product.variants
    end
  end

## Instance method, if you don't want aclass method, use this instance method
def my_instance_method
  ## code for method
end
```

**Then, call it by including common.rb in the controller***

```
include Common

def index
  ## This will make @product and @vari available
  Product.get_products_and_variants

  # ............
end



## Other method using same method call
def product
  ## This will make @product and @vari available
  Product.get_products_and_variants

  # .............
end
```

If you have multiple classes using this class method, you can use something like this (in `common.rb`):

```
def get_details        
  if self == Product
     ## Get products
  elsif self == Variant
     ## Get variants
  elsif self == ProductDetail
     ## Get product details
  end              
end
```

Comment: can i use something like this.....                                                                                      product = Product.all                                                                                        product_category = ProductCategory.all                                                              product_sub_category = ProductSubCategory.all                                            properties = product_sub_category.properties

Comment: yes @Manikandan,,for multiple Classes using same class method in common.rb,,i will suggest using if elseif way of coding(like method get_details),so that you can check which class is calling such as self==Product and can go ahead.you can also eager load using includes :)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Milind ...This helped me solve my issue......thankyou once again for spending your prescious time on this....:)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
class GenericController < ActiveRecord::Base
  def index
    do something interesting
  end
end

class PropertiesController < GenericController
  # index is done
end

class ProductsController < GenericController
  # index is done
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [before_action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action) in the controller. It will execute *find_product* before executing *index*:

```
before_action :find_product, only: :index

def find_product
    @product = Product.all
    @vari = @products.variants      
end

def index
# some useful code
end
```

You can remove the *"only:"* part to execute *find_product* before other actions, or move it to *ApplicationController* (or other parent controller class) to execute the *before_action* in all corresponding controllers.